# How to build pgRouting with CGAL?

Tags: pgrouting, cgal

When running cmake for CGAL 3.9, I get the following output:

```
root@postgresql local/CGAL-3.9# cmake -DWITH_CGAL_Qt3=OFF -DWITH_CGAL_Qt4=OFF -DWITH_CGAL_ImageIO=OFF .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Build CGAL from release: CGAL-3.9
-- Packagenames: CGAL-3.9
-- CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=3
-- CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=9
-- CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=
-- CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=8
-- CGAL_SOVERSION     =8.0.0
-- CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=
-- Building shared libraries
-- Targetting Unix Makefiles
-- Using /usr/bin/c++ compiler.
-- USING CMake version: 2.8.0
-- System: Linux
-- USING GCC_VERSION = '4.4.3'
-- Using gcc version 4 or later. Adding -frounding-math
-- Build type: Release
-- USING CXXFLAGS = ' -frounding-math -O3 -DNDEBUG'
-- USING LDFLAGS = ' '
-- Could NOT find GMP
-- Could NOT find MPFR
-- CGAL_Core needs GMP, cannot be configured.
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindBoost.cmake:917 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.40.0

  Boost include path: /usr/include

  The following Boost libraries could not be found:

          boost_thread

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set Boost_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupBoost.cmake:12 (find_package)
  cmake/modules/CGAL_SetupDependencies.cmake:32 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:422 (include)


-- Boost include:     /usr/include
-- Boost libraries:
-- Boost definitions:
-- USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.40.0'
...
```

I've tried various env variables.  I am wondering if I need to install / compile some other boost thing?  I have some libboost* in /usr/lib
Any suggestions on things to try would be appreciated.

Comment: If the instructions you for installing lib-boost-xyz did the rtrick, pelase accept it as an answer

Comment: It will not solve your problem, but never run cmake (or make) as root. It may cause unexpected problems, and is a bad practice anyway.

Answer (score 1):

JJ- thanks for the input.  I was digging around in those .cmake files last night.  I should have mentioned that overtired = overlooked.

in the many apt-get commands i ran, i ran the following:

```
apt-get install libboost1.40-dev
apt-get install libboost-thread1.40.0
```

I then decided to try:

```
apt-get install libboost-thread-dev
```

Then for good measure, rebooted.
Now its getting past THAT issue.  On to the next one!

Comment: No need to reboot. And if you build a package from source you always need *-dev packages.

Answer (score 0):

I spent quite sometime to build cgal a while ago. I don't remember the details anymore, but below is some of my notes. Hope it can help you. I was using boost 1.47. Obviously, I had the same problem as you have now, and it definitely is fixable.
-JJ

CGAL:

> cmake -G "MSYS MakeFiles"
>   modify the CMakeCache.txt, set the boost include directory, which would be in the local/include of msys
>   May also need to modify Cmake/modules/FindBoost.cmake, if you have trouble finding boost_thread library
>   I also set the env variable: BOOST_LIBRARYDIR=D:/pgroute/MinGW/msys/1.0/local/lib
>   Also modify the FindBoost.cmake, added 1.47 and 1.47.0 to the version list
>   make